# A Resource for Multi Dimensional Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a more organized array of data to parse into my template
How could I write this better? I'd like to group the arrays in their own arrays like Vars: [array], [array] ... mvData: [array], [array] ... etc..

I'd like to be able to use vars.globalVars[2] / mvData.Revenue - etc...

I am still learning about arrays - see what I have below. All the data is just figurative..

```
vars = ['Game', 'Player', 'Social Stats'];
mvData = ['22,359', '16,235', '10,938', '5,305', '12,588', '6,583'];    
evoMetric = ['Registered Players', 'Started Missions', 'Objects Bought', 'Combats', 'Guerrilla Combats', 'Teams Created', 'Guerillas created'];
playerMetric = ['playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric'];
socialMetric = ['Invitations', 'Gifts', 'Combats', 'Comic', 'Trailer', 'Illustration', 'Mission', 'Levels'];
```

Comment: Arrays aren't the correct solution; use objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, you can easily create complex data structures. The following is a valid object

```
myObject = {"property1": "value1", 
            "property2": "value2", 
            "subobject": {"subproperty": "subvalue"},
            "aubarray": ["element1", "element2", {"innerobjectkey": "innerobjectvalue"}]};
```

Comment: thank you! for some reason all the searching wasn't clear enough for me

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this

```
var MyArray = ['some text',[second dimension array],[second dimension array,[third dimension array] ]];
```

Comment: and to call second dimension array you'd do this: MyArray[1][0],third dimension array like this: MyArray[2][1][index of what you want] more brackets for more dimensions

Answer (score 0):

You could structure it as an object:

```
{
vars: ['Game', 'Player', 'Social Stats'],
mvData: ['22,359', '16,235', '10,938', '5,305', '12,588', '6,583'], 
evoMetric: ['Registered Players', 'Started Missions', 'Objects Bought', 'Combats', 'Guerrilla Combats', 'Teams Created', 'Guerillas created'],
playerMetric: ['playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric', 'playerMetric'],
socialMetric: ['Invitations', 'Gifts', 'Combats', 'Comic', 'Trailer', 'Illustration', 'Mission', 'Levels']
}
```